# Which ping-like command to measure lowest-latency possible between two machine?

Tags: networking, ping, nic, sockets

My task is to measure the network latency between 2 machines (both 1-way and 2-way are OK).
The 2 PCs are in the same room, on the same network, and connected to the same router.

When I use the `ping` command, I get `14-18us` round-trip time. When I run `onload ping` (Solarflare kernel bypass), I get `5-7us`. But `5-7us` still seems too long.

What other commands can I use to measure the lowest latency possible between 2 machines? I only care about lowest latency, not throughput; the ideal command should send a packet with  1 byte of payload to minimize cost.

Comment: Be aware, that network works with packages. Sometimes 1byte takes longer than near the package size (MTU depends on some factors but usually around 1500bytes).

Comment: Oh, right. I hope the answer also force-flush the packet immediately (like TCP_NODELAY option in C socket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your delays are very short. But you can try to use the shorter ping and arping.

#### Shorter ping

```
ping -s 16 <destination_IP>
ping -s 0 <destination_IP>
```

Normally the ping packet default size is 84 B on layer 3 (frame length is 98 bytes).
The `-s 16` flag ask to send 44 B only (58 B frame length), i.e. smaller packet size then default value.

If `-s 0` is used then the ICMP echo request L3 packet size is 28 B (42 B frame) . It is the shortest payload. But the response packet is 60 B.

#### arping

The arping is another possibility:

```
sudo apt-get install arping
sudo arping <destination_IP>
```

eventually

```
sudo arping -S <source_IP> -i <interface> <destination_IP>
```

The request frame length is 58 B and answer is 60 B in my test.

You can check the situation, packet sizes and response times using the Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this

Comment: Is your network based on the 10 Gb/s switches? Your network responses are shorter than usual 1000BaseTX switches can provide.

Comment: It's a 25 Gb/s switch